# Low resolution boot screen

Tags: windows-10

I have a question that I can’t find an answer to anywhere. I had the following problem. I built a new computer, Ryzen 2700X, Nvidia GTX1660, 16 Gb DDR4, SSD 2.5 512 gb, Aorus B450 Pro, Win 10 OS x64 (1909). The system works very well. But there is one thing. When I press the power button, the BIOS logo meets me, then the normal loading screen of Windows 10 comes, and after a few seconds the screen becomes momentarily dark and a circle of rotating dots appears on the screen, but it is of low resolution. After that, a user login screen but with a normal resolution (1920 x 1080) appears. Once again, the system works great, but it’s very annoying this extra low-resolution boot screen.
What he did: reinstalled Windows, installed another SSD, reinstalled drivers for everything, including a video card - everything did not lead to success.
Forgive help!